# Removing attribute from SpatialPointsDataFrame with spdplyr::select() in R

Tags: r, sp

I'm trying to drop columns/attributes from a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`, using `spdplyr`, like so:

```
library(sp)
library(spdplyr)

x <- c(15.2, 15.3, 15.4, 15.5, 15.7)
y <- c(50.4, 50.2, 50.3, 50.1, 50.4)
v1 <- c(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)
v2 <- c("a","b","b","c","a")
attributes <- as.data.frame(cbind(v1,v2))
xy <- cbind(x,y)
locationsDD <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(xy, attributes)

locationsDD <- select(locationsDD, -v2)
```

With the result

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(x@data, i, j, ..., drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

With `SpatialPolygonsDataFrames` this method works without issues. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Erp, no it looks like a use-case the author of spdplyr did not test.  :[

Comment: Thanks. I see you have commited a fix. I realize my question may have been better suited as a GitHub issue.

Comment: No problem, feel free to do that in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the internal method doesn't apply drop = FALSE in the subset.

You can install from Github if you want the fix:

```
devtools::install_github("mdsumner/spdplyr")
```

But, I recommend moving to `sf` it's much better all round, and no need for spdplyr any more. Here's the code I would use (I've decided not to have auto-factor-creation):

```
library(sf)
locationsDD <- st_as_sf(data.frame(x = c(15.2, 15.3, 15.4, 15.5, 15.7), y = c(50.4, 50.2, 50.3, 50.1, 50.4), 
  v1 = c(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0), v2 = c("a","b","b","c","a"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), 
  coords = c("x", "y"))

library(dplyr)
select(locationsDD, -v2)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am in the process of migrating to `sf`, but I find myself switching back to `sp` from time to time, since I can't always find `sf` functions to fulfill all the needs of my workflow (or there are too many lines of code to do what `sp`-packages can do with one line).

Comment: True enough, but it's still probably better (probably...) to use `sf` upfront and only go to Spatial when you need to, the round-trip is easy with `as(x_sf, "Spatial")` and `st_as_sf(x_Spatial)`.  Also worth asking on the Github sites (edzer/sfr) and (r-spatial/discuss) for general queries.